# ValueError for reshape method in numpy module for plotting a ping

Tags: python, numpy

I am getting the following error when trying to run the code

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/NetworkAutomation/Python_Dev/icmp_heatmap/create_plot.py", line 107, in <module>
    main()
  File "/NetworkAutomation/Python_Dev/icmp_heatmap/create_plot.py", line 72, in main
    grid_data = np.reshape(grid_data, (num_devices, num_devices))
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6, in reshape
  File "/NetworkAutomation/Python_Dev/icmp_heatmap/pyVENV/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 298, in reshape
    return _wrapfunc(a, 'reshape', newshape, order=order)
  File "/NetworkAutomation/Python_Dev/icmp_heatmap/pyVENV/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 57, in _wrapfunc
    return bound(*args, **kwds)
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 2 into shape (2,2)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

````
          import sys
            import napalm
            import yaml
            import seaborn as sns
            import pandas as pd
            import numpy as np
            from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
            from napalm.base.exceptions import ConnectionClosedException, ConnectionException
            
            
            def main():
                with open(r"device_list.yml", encoding="utf-8") as file:
                    device_list = yaml.safe_load(file)
                    driver = napalm.get_network_driver("ios")
            
                    for device in device_list:
                        device_drv = driver(
                            hostname=device,
                            username="abcdce",
                            password="asdfasdf",
                            timeout=60,
                            optional_args={
                                "secret":"cisco"
                            },
                        )
                        try:
                            print(f"Verifying connection to {device}")
                            device_drv.open()
                        except ConnectionException:
                            print(f"Unable to connect to {device}. Removing from the list.")
            
                    device_list.remove(device)
                    print(device_list)
            
                    grid_data = np.array([])
                    for device in device_list:
                        device_drv = driver(
                            hostname=device,
                            username="abcdef",
                            password="asdfasdf",
                            timeout=60,
                            optional_args={
                                "secret":"cisco",
                                "global_delay_factor":2
                            },
                        )
            
                        print(f"Initiating tests {device}")
            
                        device_drv.open()
                        for device2 in device_list:
                            try:
                                ping_results = device_drv.ping(device2, timeout=1,  count=10, source_interface="Loopback0")
                                if "success" in ping_results:
                                    avg_response = ping_results["success"]["rtt_avg"]
                                    print(avg_response)
                                    if avg_response == 0.0:
                                        grid_data = np.append(grid_data, 9999)
                                    else:
                                        grid_data = np.append(grid_data, avg_response)
                                else:
                                    print(f"Cannot ping {device2} from {device}")
                                    grid_data = np.append(grid_data, np.nan)
                            except ConnectionClosedException as e:
                                print(f"Error: {e}")
                                print("Ping command took too long ... Need tp exit program to prevent data alignment error.")
                                sys.exit()
                        print(grid_data)
            
                        num_devices = len(device_list)
            
                        grid_data = np.reshape(grid_data, (num_devices, num_devices))
                        print(grid_data)
                        sns.set_theme()
                        df = pd.DataFrame(grid_data,
                                          index=device_list,
                                          columns=device_list)
                        print(df)
                        df.to_csv("output.csv")
            
                        plt.figure(figsize=(35,30),
                                   edgecolor="black")
                        plt.rcParams["xtick.bottom"] = plt.rcParams["xtick.labelbottom"] = False
                        plt.rcParams["xtick.top"] = plt.rcParams["xtick.labeltop"] = True
            
                        sns.set_context("paper", font_scale=4.0)
                        ax = sns.heatmap(
                            df,
                            annot=True,
                            cmap="Blues",
                            linewidths=0,
                            vmin=0,
                            vmax=300,
                            fmt="g",
                            cbar=True,
                            square=True,
                            annot_kws={"fontsize":30,
                                       "color":"black",
                                       "visible":True},
                        )
                        ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=90)
                        ax.set_yticklabels(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=0)
                        plt.savefig("output.png")
                        plt.show()
            
            if __name__ == "__main__":
                main()
    
    ```
````

Comment: What should this line actually do? `grid_data = np.reshape(grid_data, (num_devices, num_devices))`. In your case there are not enough elements in grid_data to fill the new requested array shape.

Comment: I have a yaml file with following list of devices ---
- 10.168.0.161
- 10.86.0.161
- 10.168.0.161
- 10.86.0.162
- 10.26.63.240
- 10.25.63.240
- 10.61.191.221
- 10.254.253.6
- 10.254.254.24
- 10.116.63.240                                                                           
 Its printing the data in the output console  but is not plotting the graph [  1.  21.   1.  21.  45.  35.   4. 199. 119.]

Comment: what did the `print(grid_data)` show?  The error implies it showed a 2 element array.  You have all data needed to work out why reshaping that to (2,2) doesn't work.

Comment: print(grid_data) gives 1.0
21.0
1.0
21.0
46.0
41.0
4.0
198.0
123.0

Comment: Any ideas? Why I am not able to plot with the data I have.              
1.0
21.0
1.0
21.0
45.0
36.0
4.0
198.0
Printing grid data
[  1.  21.   1.  21.  45.  36.   4. 198.]
No. of devices 
8                                                                                 cannot reshape array of size 8 into shape (8,8)                                                                                Not sure what is wrong with this line of code grid_data = np.reshape(grid_data, (num_devices, num_devices))